# how to create many content in bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, css, dynamic, popover

I want to make the popover using bootstrap but with content like text, buttons and links. How to make a popover with content like that?

Here is my script:

```
<button type="button"
   class="btn btn-lg btn-danger"
   data-toggle="popover"
   title="Popover title"
   data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">

Click to toggle popover
</button>
```

Comment: why cant you go with modal?

Comment: Like @charankumar, I would also recommend using the bootsrap modal for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the **Popover** for complex things, I would recommend **Bootstrap Modal**

You can use whatever you want inside the modal, like text, buttons and links as per your requirements.